# Find all variants of word in R

Tags: regex, r, character

I have the following words.

```
words <- c("hail(0.75)", "hail0.75", "hail0.88", "hail075", "hail1.00", "hail1.75", "hail100", "hail125", "hail1.75)", "hail150", "hail175", "hail200", "hail225", "hail275", "hail450", "hail088", "hail75", "hail80", "hail88")

     [1] "hail(0.75)" "hail0.75"   "hail0.88"   "hail075"    "hail1.00"   "hail1.75"  
     [7] "hail100"    "hail125"    "hail1.75)"  "hail150"    "hail175"    "hail200"   
    [13] "hail225"    "hail275"    "hail450"    "hail088"    "hail75"     "hail80"    
    [19] "hail88"
```

as you can see, `hail(0.75)` is repeated with various typos/formatting (i.e. `hail075`, `hail0.75`)

How can I find all occurences of `hail(0.75)` including its variants described above?

I've tried

`grep("hail[0,7,5]"), words, value = T)
[1] "hail0.75" "hail0.88" "hail075"  "hail088"  "hail75"`

to find instances of hail which contain the numbers `075`.
However, it includes `hail088` which is unwanted and excludes `hail(0.75)` which is wanted.

Comment: How is `hail75` and `hail0.75` being same?

Comment: The above values refer to sizes of hail stones.
I know it's a typo as the values for hail range between 0.25 inches and 5.00 inches. However, I shall exclude `hail75` as it could be a typo for `hail(1.75)` or `hail(0.75)`. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to remove all not digit numbers and use it as an index:

```
idx <- gsub("[^[:digit:]]","",words)
words[idx=="075"]
[1] "hail(0.75)" "hail0.75"   "hail075"
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
> x <- c("hail(0.75)", "hail0.75", "hail0.88", "hail075", "hail1.00", "hail1.75", "hail100", "hail125", "hail1.75)", "hail150", "hail175", "hail200", "hail225", "hail275", "hail450", "hail088", "hail75", "hail80", "hail88")
> x
 [1] "hail(0.75)" "hail0.75"   "hail0.88"   "hail075"    "hail1.00"
 [6] "hail1.75"   "hail100"    "hail125"    "hail1.75)"  "hail150"
[11] "hail175"    "hail200"    "hail225"    "hail275"    "hail450"
[16] "hail088"    "hail75"     "hail80"     "hail88"
```

And you grep:

```
> x[grep("^hail[[:punct:]]*0[[:punct:]]*75.*", x)]
[1] "hail(0.75)" "hail0.75"   "hail075"
```

This works presuming that the 7 and the 5 are always next to each other.
Quick explanation: `^` signifies the beginning of a string, `[[:punct:]]` is any punctuation character, and `*` is the previous character (in this case the `[[:punct:]]`) repeated 0 or more times.

Comment: This is not correct. It will for example select `hail0..775`. ie.:`grep("^hail.*0.*75.*", "hail0..775")`

Comment: You are right that there could be another digit in between, so I adjusted the grep to include [[:punct:]]. Nevertheless I prefer one-liners.